# Contao 4.4 Issue with Backend Element

Tags: issue-tracking, contao

I have installed contao 4.4. 
For Dynamic content Element i'm using module 'agoat/contao-customcontentelements'. I'm facing this issue in BE 
[image]

**Anyone can help me in this ?**

Comment: May be you should report this here: https://github.com/agoat/contao-customcontentelements-bundle/issues
Also I would recommend https://github.com/madeyourday/contao-rocksolid-custom-elements/ as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how contao displays the content elements in the backend (as a ul list). So every wrapper will disrupt the backend layout of contao.

The latest version of [contao-customcontentelements](https://packagist.org/packages/agoat/contao-customcontentelements) now includes an option to have a separate template for the backend.

Comment: That is not true. See https://github.com/madeyourday/contao-rocksolid-custom-elements/blob/v2.2.3/src/Element/CustomElement.php#L99-L105 . If a RockSolid Custom Element is defined as a wrapper, it will not generate any custom HTML output in the back end. Your own extension should either do the same or at least use a `be_` template instead. See https://github.com/contao/core-bundle/blob/4.5.6/src/Resources/contao/elements/ContentSliderStart.php#L34-L43 for example.

Comment: You're right. I didn't know about that method in the RockSolid Custom Elements extension. I will correct my Answer.

Comment: But why should I use a custom elements extension to generate a wrapper element that exists in the core already (slider start/stop)??
BTW the aGoat Custom Content Elements extensions provides some template methods (currently undocumented) to handle the first and last elements of a group (see the answer on github https://github.com/agoat/contao-customcontentelements-bundle/issues/166#issuecomment-368422991)

Comment: My link was a general example of what you should do, when you have a content element that is a _wrapper_.